# How to change value of labels with the help of slider in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, slider, uislider

I have got stuck. I want to change label text when I slide slider from left to right or right to left. I have a minimum value and maximum value with a change interval.

I can show you a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 4):

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
   label.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
}
```

[image: Ctrl + Drag from slider to the view controller class and create the following action]

Comment: You should add an explanation of your code, not just pasting

Comment: as your image added image slider will be like `@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: Any)` , then if you have to a check if the sender is `UISlider`